How to retrieve the QPalette colors for the css ::hover state?
I write this minimal example that prints the QPalette colors for the "states", "default", hover and disabled, but for the hover state it didnt retrieve the colors correctly.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setObjectName("widget");
    QSpinBox* spinBox = new QSpinBox();
    spinBox->setObjectName("spinBox");
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
    textEdit->setFixedSize(60, 20);
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
    layout->addWidget(spinBox);
    layout->addWidget(textEdit); // random widget to have something else to grab focus

    widget->setStyleSheet(R"(
#spinBox
{
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 255);
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 255);
}
#spinBox::hover
{
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 255);
    color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 255);
}
#spinBox::disabled
{
    background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 255);
    color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 255);
}
    )");
    widget->show();

    static const auto colorToString = [](const QColor& color) -> QString
    {
        return QString("rgba: %1, %2, %3, %4").arg(color.red()).arg(color.green()).arg(color.blue()).arg(color.alpha());
    };

    static const auto printPallete = [](const QPalette& pal)
    {
        #define qq qDebug().noquote().nospace()
        qq << "\n ------ state ------\n"        << pal.currentColorGroup();
        //qq << "\nWindowText:\n"               << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::WindowText));
        //qq << "\nButton:\n"                   << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Button));
        qq << "\color\n"                        << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::ButtonText));
        //qq << "\nLight:\n"                    << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Light));
        //qq << "\nDark:\n"                     << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Dark));
        //qq << "\nMidlight:\n"                 << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Midlight));
        //qq << "\nText:\n"                     << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Text));
        //qq << "\nBrightText:\n"               << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::BrightText));
        //qq << "\nBase:\n"                     << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Base));
        qq << "\nbackground-color\n"            << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Window));
        //qq << "\nShadow:\n"                   << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Shadow));
        //qq << "\nHighlight:\n"                << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Highlight));
        //qq << "\nHighlightedText:\n"          << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::HighlightedText));
        //qq << "\nAlternateBase:\n"            << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::AlternateBase));
        //qq << "\nPlaceholderText:\n"          << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::PlaceholderText));
        //qq << "\nAccent:\n"                   << colorToString(pal.color(QPalette::Accent));
    };
    QObject::connect(new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F1), widget), &QShortcut::activated, [&]
    {
        spinBox->setEnabled(true);
        printPallete(spinBox->palette());
    });
    QObject::connect(new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F2), widget), &QShortcut::activated, [&]
    {
        spinBox->setEnabled(false);
        printPallete(spinBox->palette());
    });
    return a.exec();
}

Pressing the F1 shortcut while the QSpinBox is not hovered:
------ state ------
QPalette::Active
color
rgba: 1, 1, 1, 255

background-color
rgba: 1, 1, 1, 255

Pressing the F1 shortcut while hovering the QSpinBox:
 ------ state ------
QPalette::Active
color
rgba: 1, 1, 1, 255

background-color
rgba: 1, 1, 1, 255

It should be 2, 2, 2 as the stylesheet:
#spinBox::hover
{
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 255);
    color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 255);
}

Hitting F2 the shortcut disables the widget, reading the palette data it prints:
 ------ state ------
QPalette::Disabled
color
rgba: 3, 3, 3, 255

background-color
rgba: 3, 3, 3, 255

How i could read the hover colors for the text and background of a QWidget styled using stylesheet?

tl;dr
You can't.
Explanation
Qt only coincidentally updates the widget palette, but only for its known color groups, and only when a style sheet is applied (also considering the inherited ones, and including the QApplication one).
The only QPalette color groups are Disabled, Active (or Normal) and Inactive, and there is no group for the "hover" state.
There is absolutely no palette change when the state of a widget changes: what you see is only the result of the currentColorGroup(), which is set when the palette() property getter is called: before returning the QPalette, QWidget internally checks its state and calls setCurrentColorGroup() accordingly:

if the widget is not enabled, it's set to Disabled;
if it is not visible or is part of an active window, it uses the Active group;
otherwise, it uses the Inactive group;

Further calls to the returned QPalette's color() or brush() that do not use the color group will always be based on the group set above.
In fact, you would get the same results by calling the full color() syntax, no matter the current widget state: for instance, calling pal.color(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::ButtonText) even if the widget is enabled.
There is no immediate way to know colors used in pseudo-states except for those related to the QPalette color groups (including their :!<state> negations):

:active
:disabled
:enabled

If any rule defines colors using other pseudo states (like :hover) then those colors are not retrievable.
Also, since some basic rules may only set generic colors (and internally set the palette), it's also possible that the widget may still rely on the underlying base style depending on the widget and QStyleSheetStyle implementation, which may consider the palette only as a reference, not as an absolute color-rule to follow.
Which means that even if you get the color from the palette, what is eventually shown may be slightly (or even completely) different.
Conclusions and further reading
As initially said, there is no way to get colors for widget states different from enabled/active ones.
QSS (Qt Style Sheets) are quite powerful and handy for simple cases, but also tricky and somehow unreliable, unless you really know how they work and how they're applied.
Qt provides no API for retrieving the possible colors used in any given QSS state; nor it could, actually, also because of the style-related reason noted above.
The only way would be to get the current widget style sheet (including all the inherited ones, up to the QApplication), parse their contents and logically consider them, which would obviously be quite an effort, especially considering possible partially inherited rules or even being aware of rules that haven't been applied due to syntax errors or invalid values.
Still, it could be pointless, since the underlying style (or widget implmay override that to begin with.
Consider that known attempts in creating "full styles" only based on QSS eventually had to switch to fully implemented QStyles written in C++; while they are more difficult to write, they're more powerful, reliable and also performant. Consider that the "cascading nature" of QSS creates not only a benefit for their inheritance, but also a huge drawback: whenever a style sheet changes (including changes on any parent) it causes a full recomputation of the style for each possibly involved widget.
That may be fine for environments imagined and built on such logical structures (web engines), but not so good on the Qt side, which follows different implementation paths.
Related links:

How to get the color of a widget text, and set it as the color of another widget, an explanation about what palette group/color combinations are set and may be retrieved;
Say No to Qt Style Sheets, an article on the matter written by a large Qt contributor;

